# python module in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm using python in virtualenv. I have following module:

`offers/couchdb.py`:

```
from couchdb.client import Server

def get_attributes():
    return [i for i in Server()['offers']]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_attributes()
```

When I run it from file I get:

```
$ python offers/couchdb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "offers/couchdb.py", line 1, in <module>
    from couchdb.client import Server
  File "/Users/bartekkrupa/D/projects/commercial/echatka/backend/echatka/offers/couchdb.py", line 1,     in <module>
    from couchdb.client import Server
ImportError: No module named client
```

But when I paste it into interpreter... it works:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from couchdb.client import Server
>>> 
>>> def get_attributes():
...     return [i for i in Server()['offers']]
... 
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     print get_attributes()
...
```

What may be the couse that python running that module from file doesn't load couchdb module, but running in REPL does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've stumbled across a misfeature: *relative imports*.  When you say `from couchdb.client...`, Python first looks for a module under `offers.` that's named `couchdb`.  And it finds one: the file you're working on, `offers/couchdb.py`!

The usual fix is to disable this behavior, which is gone in Python 3 anyway.  Put this as the first line of Python code in your file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Then Python will assume you want to import from a top-level module named `couchdb` (which you do), not a sibling of the current module.

Unfortunately, in this case, you're running the file directly, and Python will still add `offers/` to its search path.  When running a file that's intended to be a module, you can run it with `-m`:

```
python -m offers.couchdb
```

Now it should work.

(You could, of course, just not name your file `couchdb.py`.  But I find it's pretty useful to have modules named after the thing they interact with or wrap.)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
See Eevee's answer above - I think it fits better.
Still, this might be helpful for others(?):

Maybe you did not install couchdb in your virtualenv?
That could explain why it works in the interpreter (if the interpreter is *not* launched from the virtualenv.

Either install it there or create the virutalenv with --site-packages.

Comment: interpreter is launched from virtualenv for sure :)